# for each loop for nested tree map

Tags: java, treemap

I have a nested treeMap and need to check each of the inner map if it has a certain key. For instance:

```
TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>> map

for each loop {
//check if the inner map has the key in it
}
```

How would I format the for-each loop?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `entrySet()` of the Map to iterate through the entries in a map as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    if (entry.getValue().containsKey(key)) {
        return entry.getValue().get(key);
    }
}
```

Or you can use the `values()` collection of the Map to iterate through the entries:

```
for (TreeMap<String, Integer> value : map.values())
{
    if (value.containsKey(key)) {
        return value().get(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over two nested maps with two nested "foreach" loops, like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>> entry1 : map.entrySet()) {
    Map<String,Integer> innerMap = entry1.getValue();
    if (innerMap.containsKey("my-key")) {
        System.out.println("Map at key "+entry1.getKey()+" contains 'my-key'");
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to check the inner map, not iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

Get the values from the outer map, iterate the elements inside each. In each element, which is a `TreeMap<String,Integer>`, use `containsKey` to check if the map element contains the desired key.

```
    TreeMap<String,TreeMap<String,Integer>> map = 
                                  new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String,Integer>>();
    for(TreeMap<String,Integer> mapElement: map.values()) {
        //check if the inner map has the key in it
        if(mapElement.containsKey("searchKey")){
            System.out.println("Match key found in this map element");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use Guava [TreeBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html), there are many handy methods to handle your nested data structure.

```
TreeBasedTable<String, String, Integer> tb = TreeBasedTable.create();
tb.put("rowA", "colA", 1);
tb.put("rowB", "colB", 2);

tb.containsRow("rowA");
...
```